# Can't connect to apache webserver running in docker container on ec2

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2

Can't connect to apache webserver running in docker container on ec2.
Container was built from dockerfile:

FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install apache2
RUN echo 'Hello World from Docker!' > /var/www/html/index.html
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D","FOREGROUND"]
EXPOSE 80

Then I run commands:
docker build -t app1 .
docker run -d -p 1234:80 app1:latest

curl from ec2 to 127.0.0.1:1234 or to private_ip:1234 or to docker_ip:1234 works fine
But I can't open it through public_ip via browser from the internet.

Security_group allows traffic for 80,443,22 and 1234 port from anywhere.
NACL allows everything
I tested ports through ncat and machines can communicate through 1234 port...

I am ready to try any suggestions to resolve the issue!

Comment: Is your EC2 in a public subnet(with route to internet/ with internet gateway)?

Comment: Yes, of course. I can SSH into it and ping google from there.

Comment: Just to confirm you access the page at http(not https)://$publicip:1234 right? Also, what error do you get? Is it a timeout or something else? If it's a timeout, open all traffic from anywhere and confirm the issue is related to whitelisting.